# how to store double colon values in oracle database table

Tags: excel, oracle, sqldatatypes, varchar2

I have `excel` which i am trying to import in oracle database table.

Some of the values in excel consist of for example `14:39.5` with double colon. What dataype in oracle database table i should provide to store this value ?

Currently have given `varchar` datatype and its throwing an error during import as :

```
Conversion error! Value: "00:12:01.615518000" to data type: "Number". Row ignored! Value is '00:12:01.615518000'. Cannot be converted to a decimal number object. Valid format: 'Unformatted'
```

Comment: You said, "Currently have given varchar datatype " but the error says you declared it as a NUMBER.  So which is it?  I'd suggest you start by updating your question to show the DDL for the table.  And explain exactly what '14:39.5' actually represents. Is it supposed to be a time of day?  An elapsed time?  Something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it as an `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(9)` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  time INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(9)
);
```

Then you can use `TO_DSINTERVAL` passing your value with `'0 '` prepended to the start:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (time)
VALUES ( TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || '00:12:01.615518000') );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a516c1bbb6954ea13831d2b84149aeb)*

Answer (score 1):

If it is part of a date/time stamp then you could store it as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` if you could add the date component. Oracle doesn't have just a `TIME` data type.

If you can't add a date component to it, then assuming it is a time interval you could convert it to seconds or microseconds (lose the colons) and store it as a `NUMBER`.

If you want to maintain the exact formatting as shown, your only option is to store it as text using `VARCHAR2` or something similar.